# Firefox 12 not reloading pages after redirect

Tags: php, firefox, caching

[image: Flowchart diagram]I have written a login script to redirect back to the index page once you have logged in, and thus reloading the index page for a logged in user, it just displays the previously loaded index page. The new Firefox 12 update doesn't reload the index page once the login script has redirected it back. This problem occurs again and again throughout my site when the processing script redirects Firefox back to a page it has already loaded.

Ive tried turning off caching in PHP with:

```
<?php
header( "Last-Modified: " . gmdate( "D, j M Y H:i:s" ) . " GMT" );
header( "Expires: " . gmdate( "D, j M Y H:i:s", time() ) . " GMT" );
header( "Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate" );
header( "Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", FALSE );
header( "Pragma: no-cache" ); ?>
```

and in `.htaccess` with:

```
<filesMatch "\.(php)$">
FileETag None
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
</ifModule>
</filesMatch>
```

Can anyone explain why Firefox 12.0 is doing this? It doesn't do it in other browsers. How can it be solved as soon as possible?

Thanks.

UPDATE:
It worked fine in the previous version of Firefox and all other browsers. All it's doing is redirecting back to the index page where it should reload for the newly logged in user, yet it still displays the original home page. When you click a link to the homepage it will then load the homepage properly for the user.

Comment: Does it display with SHIFT + REFRESH? If it doesn't then that means firefox doesn't support your code. If it does, then I have no idea.

Comment: It worked fine in the previous version of Firefox and all other browsers. All it's doing is redirecting back to the index page where it should reload for the newly logged in user, yet it still displays the original home page. When you click a link to the homepage it will then load the homepage properly for the user.

Comment: That's weird, do you want to give me the link so I can try it? Maybe it is a weird setting on your computer?

Comment: It's a recurring problem on multiple machines. I tried it on my laptop with Firefox 10.02 and it was fine. Updated it to 12.0 and the problem occurred. It's tricky for me to let you test it as you would need to sign up to the site and validate your email and then log in to see it not working.

Comment: show us the redirect code you use in php.

Comment: That's find if you have tested it on multiple machines. That I have no idea. It should work. What happens when you turn off your cache completely?

Comment: You used `header ("location: index.php")` right?

Comment: well that's wrong for a start, location has to be an absolute URI

Comment: I used header("Location: /index.php");, and it works with network.http.use-cache as false in about:config. I'm starting to suspect if it is a firefox bug, remember it works fine on other browsers and lower versions of FF.

Comment: no it doesn't, it works fine without having it absolute.

Comment: I agree @zoltan, it most likely is

Comment: yes it does, read the manual *HTTP/1.1 requires an absolute URI as argument to » Location* It only 'works' because current browsers ignore the standard, but what will you do when one obeys it?

Comment: are you sure? I have tried relative and it works fine.

Comment: i'm sure its in the standard, yes.

Comment: Then I guess I'll have to change all my code...

Comment: maybe ff12 obeys the standard, that's the point.

Comment: either way, the problem still occurs with header ("location: http://test.com/index.php")

Comment: that is *NOT* an absolute URL

Comment: It was until Stack overflow formatted it

Comment: apologies then, some people don't know there URI's from their URL's absolute or relative.

Comment: I've found a work around: header("Location: /?nocache=" . rand ()); adding 'nocache=" . rand ()' onto all redirects is messy but will do until a solution is found.

Comment: +1 I've started experiencing this on FF12 on multiple computers on sites which have been working fine for a while too. Your temporary solution with ?nocache=<?=rand()?> does work, but obviously isn't ideal! It does indeed appear to be a FF12 bug of some sort.

Comment: http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/926043 worth subscribing to perhaps

Comment: Careful when doing multiple redirects - those aren't reliable without a page loaded in between.

Comment: Firefox 13 resolves this issue. See [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/926043#answer-338513)

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed the same issue after upgrading from Firefox 11 to 12. My shopping cart no longer works correctly unless I append a random string to the URL on each request.

http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/926043

Answer (score 1):

just set

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
```

before your

```
header("Location:".$url);
```

greetings, daniel

Answer (score 0):

Do your redirection with javascript then:

```
<?php 
    $url = "/index.php";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
            window.location='" . $url . "';
          </script>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes php redirects work much better w/

```
 header( "Location: index.php" ) ;
 header ("Content-Length: 0");
 exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

An interesting trick I saw on other posts regarding preventing FF from caching a page.  This is an older doc, but maybe still applies: (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_Firefox_1.5_caching), saying that FF does not cache pages w/ unload or onbeforeunload events.

How about adding an onbeforeunload event that does nothing:

```
<script>
    window.onbeforeunload = function(){} //add onbeforeunload
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a timestamp to your redirection URL:

```
http://yourdomain.com/index.php?time=0205122019
```

I think that it is a cache problem.